# Connecting two residential units grounds via metallic electrical box and armored cabling

Tags: electrical, grounding

A circuit from Unit A and a circuit from Unit B converge in a metallic box. The wiring is old armored cable containing two conductors. There is no dedicated ground conductor. Each unit has its own panel.

Does this mean that we have tied the grounds together between the units via the metallic box? Is that a Very Bad Thing? I could imagine if one of the panels lost its ground, the ground path could try to flow through the path created by the armored cables converging in the metallic box.

Comment: Ground not that bad.  Now if the neutrals or hots were combined that would be very bad.  I would probably replace the single box with two boxes so mistakes cannot be made.  This will also prevent live circuit being powered on when working with the other circuit with its power off.  I am assuming this box is just a simple junction box with just wires connected together.

Comment: You should make sure the Grounding Electrode System for both units is tip top and interconnected.  Because yes, if one unit lost neutral from the utility, its neutral current would seek through the grounds to get to the other unit's neutral.

Comment: Do both units share the same service drop/lateral from the utility? Also, how is the metering and service equipment set up? (Are we talking about individual sockets or meter-mains on a trough? A multi-pack of meters with separate service disconnects? An "all in one" multimeter pack with integrated service disconnects?)